# Sending iOS push notifications from my Machine?

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications

I would like to add iOS push notification to my FREE iOS App

The push notification will be mainly advertising my other iOS applications. so I am expecting 1 or 2 push notifications every month

I checked service like urban airship, but I think it is expensive considering I have more than 1.5 Million active users.

So, what I am thinking of is collecting the devices token at Google App Engine ( java ), then whenever I want to send push notifications I export those tokens then send them from my Machine.

Is this is the right approach? what do you think?

Is there any framework that I could use instead of building things from scratch?

Many thanks

Comment: Advertising through push notifications is against the terms of the iOS developer agreement you signed with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

- This approach looks ok to me. Having an app on Google App Engine to whom each of the iOS device is sending their device token. Later at any time utilizing a web page or web service running on Google App Engine APP you can push custom notification to all respective device tokens. Just keep in mind to filter the list of device tokens with obsoleted ones (in case somebody uninstall your app).
- You may check http://code.google.com/p/javapns/ for APNS communication. I tried it couple of times and it worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

You should also give http://www.scringo.com a try.
Among other things this framework does, it also gives you a free push notifications service to send push messages to all your users or some of them (based on your custom criteria).